# RIA service default required attribute

Tags: validation, silverlight-4.0, ria

I have an EF4 model with table's columns doesn't allow null.
At the SL client application I always receieve the "columnName is required" because I have the binding in xaml with [NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True] for the textboxes.

My questions is:
I can overide the default required errormessage at the metadata class, but how can I have it as a custom validation? I mean I don't wnat to do this at the sealed metadata class:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Coin English Name Is required")]
[CustomValidation(typeof (CustomCoinVaidation), "ValidateCoinName")]
public string coin_name_1 { get; set; }
```

I want to have it inside the custom validation method that I will define for all types of errors regards that coin_name_1, as follows:

```
    public static ValidationResult ValidateCoinName(string name, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The Coin Name should be specified", new [] { "Coin Name" });
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

> Why?

for two reasons :
1- Group all the validation isdie one container (for easy localization further).
2- I don't want the coin_name_1 to be displayed to the end-user, but a meanigful as "Coin English Name".

Second question:
I have a ValidationSummary control on my xaml page where all the errors are displayed but is displaying the orignal name of the column "coin_name_1" how can I chnge that to be a meanigfil also.

Best regards
Waleed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1:
I just left the required as it is implemented right now..

A2:
I went through different sources and find this artical.
It shows how to style the validation summary:
http://www.ditran.net/common-things-you-want-know-about-silverlight-validationsummary

I am also implementing a client-side validation asyncronizly.

Regards

Comment: from the suggested link I can say the following
is this right, each page xaml has to have it? all this xaml code to show validation error, how can I have all this code in a single place(whatever it is) where I can show validation error for any xaml web page.
Any body would like to help on this.

Comment: @ramnz propobley you have this sorted out, if not here is it. you can have the xaml styling the validation summary at the appliation level inside your resource file assign x:key to it and use it all over your app as needed.